# Use react native hooks for state in changing components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm building my first react native application and am having trouble fully understanding the newly introduced react hooks

Based on the user using the app (and hence an API call), I have a number of `PeopleListItem` components per user. In each `PeopleListItem` I want to set a state, that changes based on the users actions in the app. So user John doe could render a page with two `PeopleListItem` components as follows:

```
<PeopleListItem>
   // Somewhere in the component definition
   const [attributeVale, setAttributeValue] = useState("Whatever")
</PeopleListItem>
<PeopleListItem>
   // Somewhere in the component definition
   const [attributeVale, setAttributeValue] = useState("Whatever")
</PeopleListItem>
```

This errors with:

> Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

I'm a bit confused by this, as the number of `PeopleListItem` is static, it's just not known up front and hence a db call needs to be made. Theoretically though, I would want to change the number of `PeopleListItem`. Is it possible to use react native hooks for this use case? If not, what would be the correct approach to use states in a variable number of components?

```
export default function PeopleScreen() {
  const [snapshot, loading, _error] = useCollectionOnce(
    firebase.firestore().collection("people"),
  );

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        {snapshot.docs.map((doc) => PeopleListItemComponent({ peopleDoc: doc }))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}


export function PeopleListItemComponent(props: PeopleListProps) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');

  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Why isn't this working?");

  });
  return("")
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual component definition (at least up to the line where you call `useState`)?

Comment: It's actually the first line of the component defnition!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you revealed more code from `PeopleListItem` . With what you have shown, any suggestion provided would just be taking a shot in the dark. If I had to take a shot in the dark, I would guess that there's an if-else block above an useEffect (the only time I have ever seen this error was from that). So I would recommend moving your all your effects to end of your code (by end I mean right above your return statement)

Comment: I added the PeopleListItem and PeopleScreen component definition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using hooks, you have to make sure that you call the same hooks in the same order on each render of a given component. In other words, you have to follow [The Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

The problem in your example is here:

```js
<ScrollView>
    {snapshot.docs.map((doc) => PeopleListItemComponent({ peopleDoc: doc }))}
</ScrollView>
```

You are calling `PeopleListItemComponent` like a regular function. Since it contains hooks, you will get an error if you don't call `PeopleListItemComponent` the same number of times on each render. It's just as if you called those hooks directly from within the `map` callback.

What you really want to do is render a React element for each item in `docs`. Make sure to give each element a unique [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) too.

```js
<ScrollView>
    {snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
        <PeopleListItemComponent
            key={doc.id}
            peopleDoc={doc}
        />
    ))}
</ScrollView>
```

It's perfectly OK to render components conditionally or within a loop, even if the component itself contains hooks. You just have to make sure to follow the Rules of Hooks within the body of each component.